# Coldest temperatures achievable in DIY enthusiast/hobbyist setting

Tags: home-experiment, cooling, cryogenics

Assume I, as a physics DIY enthusiast, would like to **cool** a little piece of material down to **coldest possible temperatures**, for my own entertainment or my private curiosity/research ambitions. We all know that without much hassle many people in today's western societies could afford a conventional freezer (at least on the used market) which can get down to -20°C or -30°C without problems. Now that's still ~ 240 K.

Now hobbyists have built multi-stage Peltier coolers, which can get down to about -60°C. Now that's still ~ 210 K.

Now ambitious hobbyists (rapp instruments; applied science youtube channel) have constructed or refurbished chillers or (multi-stage) Pulse-Tube, Stirling or Gifford-McMahon cryocoolers, with air as operating gas, but these projects are already at quite a sophisticated level of technicality for average Joe. They are fundamentally limited by the dew point of air to about -180°C at best, or 90 K. Now, it would be possible to go lower than this ~ 100 K range if one could use helium as operating gas, but due to the high cost of helium this is not an option for most hobbyists.

Now I've recently read about magnetic cooling principles, and adiabatic demagnetization refrigeration (ADR). From all I can tell, the practical implementation of the technique is technically very challenging. TU Munich spin-off kiutra now sells commercial units using this technique, but as far as I understand the units use pre-cooling stages based on closed-cycle helium machines. The amount of engineering required to built a closed-cycle helium pre-cooling aparatus for this, let alone the all-integrated ADR, probably goes beyond even the most ambitious hobbyists.

I am wondering what might be the **most promising route** for **DIY enthusiasts/hobbyists** to pass the ~ 100 K barrier and cool (be it only very small) samples **into the some few tens of Kelvin range or lower** *.

*the answer "Hopeless, this will forever remain a temperature range only accessible to research/industry labs" doesn't count ;). Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Depends how much liquid nitrogen you want to buy.

Comment: I was thinking it shouldn't be more expensive than what an average Joe in the western world is willing to pay for a hobby, so maybe not much more then some 10s or 100s of euros/dollars. Personal working hours of course not included in the cost (it's a hobby).

Comment: Check gas suppliers in your area. It’s about a buck a gallon (ish), cheaper than milk.

Comment: Put liquid nitrogen inside a bell jar and use a vacuum pump to lower the pressure.  See http://www.peacesoftware.de/einigewerte/stickstoff_e.html

Comment: An here is how you make your own liquid nitrogen. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCXkaQa53QQ

Comment: You might have fun researching how, say, Onnes, did his experiments. A century later many things are easier.

Comment: @JonCuster: This is an excellent suggestion. Maybe it will give me some ideas for hacks.

Comment: @mmesser314: I checked out the video, but this is kinda dull. He starts out with just buying a research grade cryocooler, and calls his video "from scratch".

Comment: @DavidWhite: nice idea about reducing the pressure on a sample of bought liquid nitrogen. Unfortunately it will only get you a couple of degrees lower from the boiling point of liquid nitrogen at atmospheric pressure, which is ~77 K. It's not sufficient to go to the few ten Kelvin range or lower. Still a nice idea and probably the cheapest to get to the 65 to 70 Kelvin range.

Comment: Once you pump down to a temperature where the pressure of N2 fall off, you are stuck with working with He. Expensive, but it will get you much farther. One benefit: At low temperatures, the specific heat of things drops. You are starting at 80K, and you don't need to remove as much heat to drop a degree as you would at room temp. So it is less expensive than it would be.